# Get customers that has more than 2 orders but logged in less than 3 times though SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all customers who has more than 2 orders, but only logged in less than 3 times.

I'm logging when users are logging in.

But for some reason my returns only one row with wrong data...

**"user_log" table (user_id 19 has logged in only once)**

```
| user_log_id | date | user_id | type | module_id | unit_id |
|-------------|------|---------|------|-----------|---------|
|      1      |"date"|   19    |  1   |   NULL    |   NULL  |
|      2      |"date"|   20    |  1   |   NULL    |   NULL  |
|      3      |"date"|   20    |  1   |   NULL    |   NULL  |
|      4      |"date"|   20    |  1   |   NULL    |   NULL  |
|      5      |"date"|   20    |  1   |   NULL    |   NULL  |
|-------------|------|---------|------|-----------|---------|
```

**"orders" table where user_id 19 has 2 orders (Removed unnecessary columns)**

```
| order_id | user_id | status |
|----------|---------|--------|
|    10    |   19    |   1    | 
|    11    |   19    |   1    |
|    12    |   20    |   1    |
|    13    |   21    |   1    |
|    14    |   31    |   1    |
|----------|---------|--------|
```

**What i want (User_id has 2 orders, but has logged in less than 3 times)**

```
| user_id |
|---------|
|    19   |
|---------|
```

This is how my SQL looks like right now.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            ul.*, orders.order_id, orders.user_id, orders.firstname, orders.lastname, COUNT(ul.user_id) AS occourcence                
        FROM 
            orders
        LEFT JOIN
            user_log AS ul
        ON
            orders.user_id = ul.user_id
        WHERE 
            orders.status = 1
        AND
            ul.type = 1
        GROUP BY    
            orders.user_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(orders.user_id) > 1
        ORDER BY 
            orders.order_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select user_id,count(user_log_id) from user_log
where user_id in
            (
                select user_id from Orderes
                            group by user_id
                            having count(order_id) =2
                    )
group by user_id
having count(user_log_id) < 3
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! You just made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding any sub queries (and assuming you meant logged in 3 times, and making 2 **or more** orders - to match your example data):-

```
SELECT a.user_id
FROM user_log a
INNER JOIN orders b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY a.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_log_id) < 3 AND COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) >= 2;
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b719/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select o.user_id from
(
    select user_id from orders
    where status=1 
    group by user_id having count(*)>=2
) as o left join
(
    select user_id from user_logs
    where type=1
    group by user_id having count(*)<3
) as l
on o.user_id=l.user_id
```

Comment: Correct ans, but we can avoid using two subqueries.